# Como enviar JSONObject para um Web Service?

Tags: java, android, json, web-service

Eu estou tentando pela primeira vez consumir um Web Service no meu aplicativo em Android, enviando dados por formato JSON.

Para realizar a tarefa tenho uma classe para fazer a conexão.

```
public class ConexaoHttpJson {

public static JSONObject enviarSolicitacao(String urlPost,JSONObject obj) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {      

    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlPost); 
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    //post.setHeader("Authorization",token);
    //post.setHeader("Cookie","ASP.NET_SessionId="+sessao+"; path=/; HttpOnly");

    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString()));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post,localContext);  

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

    String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);

    JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);

    Log.i("json servidor", jsonObjRecv.toString());
    instream.close();

    return  jsonObjRecv;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Agora eu preciso do HTML e do `ObjectJson`, no qual estou criando numa classe `Activity`, nesse formato:

```
    public void onClickConnect(View view) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {                       
                 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                 json.put("email", login.getText().toString()); 
                 json.put("password", senha.getText().toString());

                 String url = "http://webservice.com/Api.php?user=logar";//EXEMPLO
                 JSONObject response = ConexaoHttpJson.enviarSolicitacao(url, json);                           
                 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
        }.start();   
    }
```

Eu quero é enviar uma URL, e email e senha em formato JSON, pegar a resposta do WebService e trabalhar em cima dela.

O problema está na linha do método `enviarSolicitação`.

```
   String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);        
   JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
```

Log do erro

```
05-13 22:48:25.430: W/System.err(1951): org.json.JSONException: Value <meta of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-13 22:48:25.430: W/System.err(1951):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-13 22:48:25.430: W/System.err(1951):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
05-13 22:48:25.430: W/System.err(1951):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
05-13 22:48:25.430: W/System.err(1951):     at com.sostudy.ConexaoHttpJson.enviarSolicitacao(ConexaoHttpJson.java:44)
05-13 22:48:25.430: W/System.err(1951):     at com.sostudy.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:153)
```

Comment: Raul, em que linha deu o erro? E qual é o erro? :)

Comment: Quando uso o Debug ele para na linha:
`json.put("email", login.getText().toString()); `

Comment: `login.getText()` por acaso não está retornando `null`?

Comment: Realmente isso estava ocorrendo, eu coloquei valores fixos nos campos, agora vi que estou com algum problema no método enviarSolicitacao, vou tentar descobrir o problema, valeu.

Comment: Ou será que `login` é `null`?

Comment: Alterei a pergunta, a questão do login null eu consertei, a inserção dos valores nas váriaveis login e senha estava ocorrendo fora do tempo correto.

Comment: Poderia postar a String de resposta? Me parece que isso tem mais haver com erro de formatação ou encoding do JSON da resposta do que propriamente a implementação que você fez.

Comment: @RaulPires, se possível post o conteúdo da variável `resultString`, que é retorno, acredito que a string de retorno do web service não está no formato correto, para converter para o objeto JSON, por isso o `org.json.JSONException`.

Comment: Oi pessoal, muito obrigado pela atenção. Era erro no retorno do WebService. Ele estava retornando um HTML inteiro. Gostaria de fechar a questão, mas parece que não tenho como fazer isso aqui :)

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar esta linha de código, o valor do `resultString` tem que ser um JSON válido.

```
JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString)
```

Um JSON é um objeto por chave, valor em que a chave tem que ser uma string e o valor pode ser 
uma *string*, um número, um *boolean* (true ou false), um objeto JSON ou um *array* de *string*.

Provavelmente o teu `resultString` não é um Json válido.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar ter que lidiar diretamente con json no android e recomendabel utilizar GSON https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ evitar ter eses problemas en manipular string para criar json

Comment: Oscar, poderia detalhar melhor sua resposta? - [como responder](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)